# Qt 6.5 how to use c++ functions when using ui.qml and qml files

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt6, qtquick-designer

Using Qt 6.5 I have created a brand new Qt Quick Application from the Create Project button in the Welcome menu.

This new project creates some base files by default when I keep the "Create a project that you can open in Qt Design Studio" button checked:

[image]

Approaching this as a first time user of Quick, this directory structure is very confusing for me. Especially since the Qt6 docs have this seemingly simple example of how to call C++ functions from QML: [enter link description here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquick-how-tos.html)

The docs link says that I should also be creating a `qt_add_qml_module` into some CMake file so that I can `import <MyModule>`. In the project template that is generated for me, which CMake file do I add this too, and what exactly am I supposed to add?

Further, because this template that is generated upon project creation includes a `ui.qml` and you can't call functions from `ui.qml` files, what exactly should I be doing here?

I've tried to compare and contrast the example `hangman` quick project, which does include calling C++ functions. Since this example project does not include any `ui.qml` files, though, it is difficult to translate the concepts to this default project of mine.

Can someone explain how to do this? I truly need the "Explain it to me like I'm 5".

Comment: Are you saying the CMakeLists.txt files that were generated for you do not already use `qt_add_qml_module`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I did not implement it in the test project I posted above, I ultimately did the following to access c++ classes in QML:

1. Create a new `.h/.cpp` file. Add QObject as the base class, include QObject, Add Q_OBJECT, and Add QML_ELEMENT

[image: reference picture]

2. In the `.h` file, add `Q_INVOKABLE` before the function you'd like to call in QML. Add `#include <QtQml>` as it is needed to access `Q_INVOKABLE`. For example:

```
// PartyTime.h
#ifndef PARTYTIME_H
#define PARTYTIME_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QtQml>

class PartyTime : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QML_ELEMENT
public:
    explicit PartyTime(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    Q_INVOKABLE void party();

signals:

};

#endif // PARTYTIME_H
```

3. In my `CMakeLists.txt`, find the `qt_add_qml_module` function that is generated for you. Copy the `URI` value.
4. At the top of my `Main.qml` file, `import <qml-module-URI>`
5. Now you can add a QML object of your class. For example:

```
// Main.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window
import QtQuick.Controls
import <qml-module-URI>

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    PartyTime {
        id: partyTime
    }

    Button {
        id: partyTimeBtn
        text: "Click to start party"
        onClicked: partyTime.party()
    }
}
```